# Apache server hangs up on running PHP script for scaling an image

Tags: php, optimization

I have a PHP class that gets an image which is uploaded and resizes it to three different resolutions (a thumbnail, 300x300 and 800x800).

I also have a jQuery uploader which manages and uploads images, adding them to a queue.

The problem is, during the upload, the server is not taking any other requests. Also the task manager shows that the httpd.exe is taking 15% of CPU.

The code that I'm using can be found here.. 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/example/upload.php

What should I do to make the workload of server less?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to try to isolate the exact problem point. Start with commenting out the image resizing code and upload a relatively large file. Maybe like a 9MB file. If during the upload process apache still hangs then the problem is with the upload process. If it does not, then put back the three resize functions one by one and see if one those cause the hanging. Also it would be great if you could share your configuration information. Is this a shared server or dedicated(Can you change php.ini if necessary)?  How much memory does it have? Operating system? PHP/Apache version?

Comment: @Haluk i've shared the link of the code that i'm using. yes its a dedicated server. i have full control of it..! i can change any configuration through ssh. and the image uploaded is not large its 2.5Mb. the php script returns a "okay" message when the resize is complete.. the resize takes one after other in the same script..

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize the resizing, you could look into using ImageMagick instead of the php GD functions. It is also possible to have the client javascript resize to your largest supported size, say 800x800 before upload.

Finally, you could pull the resize code out of your uploader, and attach it to an ajax request sent after the upload is complete (say, having a loading gif over a placeholder where server will return thumbnail after it's done resizing)